# How to avoid “404 - File or directory not found.” when referencing a route link in Angular URL

Tags: angular, iis

How to avoid “404 - File or directory not found.” when referencing a route link in Angular?

For example this URL appears if you navigate to a page:

```
http://www.semiwebs.com/angular-semi/sagesoftware
```

and it works. But if you type this URL in a browser by itself, you get an error

> 404 - File or directory not found.

On the development machine using localhost both the navigation through the website works and `http://localhost:4200/sagesoftware` also works.

What setting am I missing that is preventing navigation on the server which is IIS7

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a single page application that handles the route on the client side. You will need to add a `rewrite` rule on your server, to redirect all routes to the `index.html` page.

What happens is that your server is trying to find the path `http://www.semiwebs.com/angular-semi/sagesoftware` which doesn't exist. You need to pass that to the `index.html` so angular know what component to show instead.

An example I found online:

**web.config**

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="SPA Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <!-- match everything by default -->
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <!-- unless its a file -->
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <!-- or a directory -->
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <!-- or is under the /api directory -->
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
            <!-- list other routes or route prefixes here if you need to handle them server side -->
        </conditions>
        <!-- rewrite it to /index.html -->
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

[IIS](https://www.mattburkedev.com/iis-rewrite-rule-for-single-page-apps/) rule for SPA's

Comment: This looks like it should  work, but where do I put the rule? I tried at the bottom of index.html to no avail. I am still trying to  find my way around the angular framework. Thanks

Comment: that gets placed in the `web.config` file that should be at the root of your project. This in paticular is not specific to angular, its more about how you web server is configurered

Comment: I placed the web.config file in the root of angular-ssi. Now when I type in the URL it displays as http://www.shelbysys.com/angular-ssi/index.html and returns a 
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.
I  am still missing something

Comment: I  used the same web.config above but removed to conditions section. Tried it  both ways.

Comment: Try this [guide](https://codepen.io/scriptmaster/post/iis-web-config-for-spa-angular-4-5-6)

Comment: Changing this line to <action type="Rewrite" url="/angular-ssi/index.html" /> and placing the web.config in the angular-ssi folder worked. Thanks for your help